# How to animate the TitleEdgeInsets coordinates in a UIButton?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uibutton, cabasicanimation

I'm developing an iOS app in Monotouch. I need to animate the TitleEdgeInsets coordinates in a custom button. I derived my custom button class from UIButton because I need to animate the button and the label when the button is pressed. The button was easy. But when it come to animating the title label I found a problem. I just need the button label to shift vertically toward the bottom. The y coordinate of the button title label can be set with: "this.TitleEdgeInsets.Top". But while setting it directly works, the property doesn't seem to animate.

Here is my tentative method:

```
     public void AnimateButtonPressing()
      {
        var button_offset = 20.0f;
        var basicAnimation = CABasicAnimation.FromKeyPath ("TitleEdgeInsets");

        basicAnimation.TimingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction.FromName (CAMediaTimingFunction.Linear);

        UIEdgeInsets oldInset = this.TitleEdgeInsets;

        UIEdgeInsets newInset = new UIEdgeInsets(button_offset,oldInset.Left,oldInset.Bottom,oldInset.Right);

        basicAnimation.From = NSValue.FromUIEdgeInsets (oldInset);

        basicAnimation.To = NSValue.FromUIEdgeInsets (newInset);

        basicAnimation.Duration = 0.5f; //0.5 seconds

        this.Layer.AddAnimation (basicAnimation, "TitleEdgeInsets"); 
      }
```

The above method doesn't work. It doesn't animate at all.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.